# What is this connector?

Tags: connectors, tnc

It is the size of a BNC but has threads.  For an RF output.

[image]

I need to adapt it to SO-239.

### ----------------------------------------------

Tip o' The Hat to Glenn and Scott.  TNC it is.

This cable works great:

[TNC Male to SO-239 pigtail](https://www.ebay.com/itm/20-TNC-male-to-PL-259-SO-239-female-RG58-cable-jumper-pigtail-MADE-IN-USA/321959141223)  (eBay)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like a female [TNC connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNC_connector).

Comment: Excellent. I found the pigtail on eBay:  https://www.ebay.com/itm/20-TNC-male-to-PL-259-SO-239-female-RG58-cable-jumper-pigtail-MADE-IN-USA/321959141223 TNX, Glenn & Scott

Comment: Cable arrived and fits perfectly.  Thanks again!

Comment: @SDsolar Excellent. I am glad it worked out.